# Get consistent snapshot of two variables

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

I have two variables that need to be obtained in a consistent snapshot

```
std::atomic<int> foo;
std::shared_ptr<Bar> baz;
```

One writer thread, one reader thread.

Is there anything better than a mutex? The reader is going to do  `foo.exchange(0)` and a swap (atomic for `shared_ptr`) for baz, but of course that doesn't guarantee consistency.

Comment: You mean, you want one thread to be able to write to both, and another thread to be unable to read 'in the middle' of the first thread writing to both?

Comment: Do you mean the writer is going to do `exchange` and `swap`? A thread doing such operations isn't usually called a "reader."

Comment: @Yakk Yes. And I can't think of anything better than a mutex, although with a single variable I could just have an atomic. (Indeed, if I use a mutex, `foo` can be a regular `int`. And I can probably move `baz` to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The idea is to read-and-reset.

Comment: Shared ptr to pair of int bar?  Then atomic is freeish.  Shared ptr to bar can be generated through "god mode" shared ptr constructor.